# Add an auto-refresh on an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe, page-refresh

I need assistance with the below code. I need to add something in so that it auto-refreshes on a regular basis. What do I need to add?

```
<iframe 
   src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRhl6HlSXkbrMcFZBSH58Jx5_VwFqzfFr0aqWcKXs4nWVfPDjwwh4vv6pLRur0nR0SKjRShN8/pubhtml?gid=1977651099&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"
   height=800 
   width=800>
</iframe>
```

I am a beginner and have no experience in coding

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(()=>{
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'); 
    iframe.reload(true); 
}, 1000) // reload once a second
```

This is my code, I hope helpful for you